# How to hide nav-bar with tabs in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, tabs, ionic3, navbar

How to hide nav-bar with tabs in Ionic 2?

I only want to hide it in one of the pages excluding others.

```
<ion-navbar *navbar   >
  <ion-title>Item Details</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

I have tried `hide-nav-bar="true"` but it does not work.

Comment: Its an issue of ionic2 https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5556

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a tab page you can do:

```
this.nav.parent.parent.setRoot(LoginPage);
```

**Before:**

*Nav -> Tabs -> somepage*

**After:**

*Nav -> LoginPage*

> Nav is the root of all nav stacks in Ionic 2

Also, a modal works well for a situation where you want to show a list item's detail in a new view without navigation tabs or a nav bar taking up valuable screen space.

Currently I don't think there is a way to hide tabs when on the child view of the tabs page other than using CSS. If you decide to go with the CSS option then I would suggest using Angular's ngClass attribute https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html to set a class than will hide the nav tabs or nav bar.

Comment: Works also in 2.0.0-rc.2

Comment: But this essentially means you don't have a back button anymore, for example to go back to the page with the tabs where you tapped something to e.g show some detail page. Imo, being able to hide the tabs on certain pages would be beneficial as the back functionality is useful.

Comment: @Johncl I get what you're saying but imo a modal would be better suited in that situation, most of the time anyway. There would definitely be exceptions.

Comment: Yes, I have gone for modals when there is only one page now, but in some cases I sort of go into a multi page wizard thing where the user should be able to navigate back at any time all the way back to the original tabbed page. I just find it a bit odd they chose to use the same navigation stack thing for the tabs, but perhaps there are a lot of applications that need one stack per tab and we are making something different? Dunno really.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to do it with css. You can add the following code on your `constructor`

```
 tabBarElement: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController) {

    if (document.querySelector('.tabbar')) {
      this.tabBarElement = document.querySelector('.tabbar.show-tabbar');
    }


  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    if (this.tabBarElement) {
      this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'none';
    }

  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    if (this.tabBarElement) {
      this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'flex';
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ionic2 has Create Hide Back Button you can try this. Code is Given Below

```
<ion-navbar *navbar hideBackButton>
    <ion-title>Item Details</ion-title>
   </ion-navbar>
```

Comment: This will only hide the back button rather than hiding the whole nav bar or nav tabs.

Comment: If you want o hide whole nav bar. Then remove the <ion-navbar> tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that hides the nav-bar:

```
//hide nav bar when we enter the page
    onPageWillEnter() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("ion-navbar-section")[0].style.display = "none";
    }

//show nav bar when we leave the page
    onPageDidLeave() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("ion-navbar-section")[0].style.display = "block";
    }
```

Credit to marcus-robinson from here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5556

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, however, this worked for me:

```
page-<page-name> ion-navbar {
  display: none !important;
}
```

This hides it only for a given page, no white-space or margin problems.