# How to hide nav-bar and tabs in Ionic 2?

Tags: css, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to hide a nav-bar and tabs (that are at the bottom) in a subpage I found a solution to use access css style and change the `display` to `none` .

I successfully hidden  the nav-bar and tabs but the problem that it still there is white space in the subpage tableView and the subpage content is between two white spaces as you can see in the screenshot

[image]

How can I solve this issue ?

this is my code to hide the nav-bar and tabs

```
    //get all tabs elements
    if (document.querySelector('.tabbar')) {
      this.tabBarElements = document.querySelectorAll('.tabbar.show-tabbar');
    }

    //get all toolbar elements
    if (document.querySelector('.toolbar')) {
      this.toolBarElements = document.querySelectorAll('.toolbar');
    }
  }

  //hide all tabs and the header toolbar when enter page
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    if (this.tabBarElements) {
      this.tabBarElements[0].style.display = 'none';
      this.tabBarElements[1].style.display = 'none';
    }

    if (this.toolBarElements) {
      this.toolBarElements[1].style.display = 'none';
    }

  }
```

**INFO**

I found what is causing the problem (see the screenshot at the bottom) but I can't make change to it with accessing CSS

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide nav-bar with tabs in Ionic 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963381/how-to-hide-nav-bar-with-tabs-in-ionic-2)

Comment: I have used the code of LeRoy from this question

Comment: I found what is causing the problem but I can't make change to it with css

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My problem was placing too tabs bars it seems that it's not supported by Ionic. So I decided to change one of them with a segments it's ok now

Answer (score 3):

For ionic 2, you can directly edit the html associated with the page like so:

```
<ion-header>
  <!--ion-navbar>      
    <ion-title>
      Login
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar-->
</ion-header>
```

or if you wanted to do it programmatically, you could do something like:

```
<ion-header>
 <span *ngIf = "hideNavBar">
   <ion-navbar>      
     <ion-title>
       {{varTitle}}
     </ion-title>
   </ion-navbar>
  </span>
</ion-header>
```

where hideNavBar is a boolean variable that you would put before the constructor (and after the class declaration) in the .ts file associated with the page, and set it to true or false to show or hide the Navigation Bar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but My problem is to hide the navbar of the parent page not of the subpage

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by parent page and subpage.  Could you, perhaps, take a screenshot of the rendered page and indicate what you are trying to modify?

Comment: For example you have a page called A whrere I put a navbar and a tabs when I navigate to another page called B with push(pageB) the navbar and the tabs of page A still exist in page A .
So page A is parent page and page B I called subpage

Comment: Ok.  I understand now.  The answer I was providing was only for the navbar, not for the tabs.  I tried Swapnil's solution and that worked on my system for the tabs.  What were you seeing with his solution that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

> Tell the content to recalculate its dimensions. resize() should be called after dynamically adding/removing headers, footers, or tabs.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  resize(){
    this.content.resize();
  }
   ionViewWillEnter() {
         if (this.tabBarElements) {
             this.tabBarElements[0].style.display = 'none';
             this.tabBarElements[1].style.display = 'none';
             this.resize();
         }

         if (this.toolBarElements) {
             this.toolBarElements[1].style.display = 'none';
             this.resize();
         }
     }
}
```

Demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/93mRrD?p=preview)

Comment: Add a button and try calling resize() on click of that button. I tried and it worked.

Comment: the white spaces still persist nothing change

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/93mRrD?p=preview. I tried doing this with header. hide header then resize.

Comment: No, but my problem was placing too tabs bars it seems that it's not supported by ionic . So I decided to change one of them with a segments it's ok now

Comment: The resize works for when the header is hidden but not for when the tabs are also hidden.  Any clues on how to make the content flow into the tabs space as well?